# How to get json data in ajax call?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I have created json data in java script. And I need to call these data in ajax function.I want to know how to call that object in ajax function.

**javascript**:

```
           var JsonData= {
          "id": "10",
          "location": "xxx"
           }
```

in ajax call:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
var dataString = JSON.stringify(JsonData);
    $.ajax({
          type:"POST",
          url:"............",
          /my auth details..../,
          contentType: 'application/json',
          dataType: 'json',
          data:dataString,
          success: function(data) 
          {
          console.log(data); 
          alert(data);
          }
    }); //End of ajax
}) // End of Document ready
```

I got error, **the json data not loaded** in my ajax function, it shows null data.

Please correct my code?

Comment: Working fine here: https://jsfiddle.net/rayon_1990/Lbtbbs5u/

Comment: I don't quite get the question... Are you trying to load data from the server  in an ajax call?

Comment: url:"............",          /my auth details..../,    ?

Comment: thanks to all, now working.problem on my server side.